# what is the problem using java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, jpa

I try to search all data using java-spring-boot with Mysql but when i run the code i got the this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'emp0_.get_company_name' in 'field list'
```

This is my Controller code

```
package com.example.rest.controller;


import com.example.rest.Emp;
import com.example.rest.service.EmpService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("emp")
public class EmpController {
    @Autowired
    private EmpService empService;

    @GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<List<Emp>> getAllEmps() {
        List<Emp> emps = empService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Emp>>(emps,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is my EmpRepository code

```
package com.example.rest.repository;
import com.example.rest.Emp;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface EmpRepository  extends JpaRepository<Emp, Integer> {
}
```

This is my EmpService Code

```
package com.example.rest.service;

import com.example.rest.Emp;

import java.util.List;

public interface EmpService {
    List<Emp> findAll();
}
```

This is my EmpServiceImpl Code

```
package com.example.rest.service;

import com.example.rest.Emp;
import com.example.rest.repository.EmpRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
@Service
public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {
    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository empRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Emp> findAll() {

        List<Emp> emps= new ArrayList<>();
        empRepository.findAll().forEach((e -> emps.add(e)));

        return emps;
    }
}
```

This is my Application Code

```
package com.example.rest;

import com.example.rest.repository.EmpRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    EmpRepository empRepository;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class , args);
    }
}
```

This is my Emp Code

```
package com.example.rest;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Emp implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idx;
    private String company_id;
    private String getCompany_name;
}
```

So if someone knows that what is the problem please tell me if you don't remind with solution

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @Service annotation on the EmpServiceImpl class and @Repository annotation on the EmpRepository.

```java
        @Service
        public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {
            @Autowired
            private EmpRepository empRepository;

            @Override
            public List<Emp> findAll() {

                List<Emp> emps= new ArrayList<>();
                empRepository.findAll().forEach((e -> emps.add(e)));

                return emps;
            }
        }

        @Repository
        public interface EmpRepository  extends JpaRepository<Emp, Integer> {

        }
```

Comment: Is working now but i got the com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'emp0_.get_company_name' in 'field list' this error do you know that why this error raised?

Comment: getCompany_name this column doesn't exist in the table company. You have to alter the table and add a column getCompany_name to the company table. For dev environment, you can set jpa:hibernate:ddl-auto: update in application yml so it can update automatically.

Comment: Always note that whenever a new field (i.e new column) is added in entity class, you need to clean restart your project with the jpa ddl setting to update or manually get the column added in database to avoid such conflicts. You can refer- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ to know more about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add annotation on below class:

```
@Service  
class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {

}
```

Comment: Duplicate answer.